# How to edit a list of checkable items like in iPhone UX in Ionic?

Tags: iphone, angular, ionic-framework, menu, edit

I want the same process of list editing as in the next two pictures.

[1st Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fJAa.png)
[2nd picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG8co.png)

I tried to do it with ngFor and by giving an index to the value I'm displaying in this ngFor, but I'm struggling to find a solution on how to recognize which element has been checked in the toggle (or radio button, whatever), so basically which element should be removed from the display.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the images, I get you are implementing radio buttons in ionic. And you'd like to recognise what element has been selected. The code below gets the value of the radio button the user clicks then removes it from the array.i is the index of the selected item to be removed,1 is the number of elements to be removed.

radio-buttons.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Radio Buttons</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
<ion-list >
  <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="food" >
    <ion-list-header>
      <ion-label>
        Food
      </ion-label>
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="onChangeHandler()">
      <ion-label>
        {{item}}
      </ion-label>
      <ion-radio slot="start" value={{item}}>
      </ion-radio>
    </ion-item>    
  </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

in your .ts file:

```
export class RadioButtonsPage implements OnInit {

  items=[];
  food;
  constructor()
   {
     this.items=
     [
       "Pizza",
       "Burgers",
       "Fries",
       "Shawarma",
       "Lemon"
     ];

    }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onChangeHandler() 
  {
    let i= this.items.indexOf(this.food);
    this.items.splice(i,1);
  }


}
```